Movie with two guys in a small house under a highway overpass and where stuff starts disappearing
This movie came out some time after 2004. It had two guys who lived in some small house that was located under a highway overpass (or perhaps on the ground in a space between two highway overpasses).
If I remember correctly there was some reason why everything started disappearing and in the end it was just those two guys in a white blank nothingness.
What movie might this have been?

Nothing. 2003. Two guys end up in house and when trying to leave find a vast nothingness. 
From IMDB

After a terrible day, two good friends and housemates find the outside
  world converted into a featureless and empty white void.

